# Is the Levi-Civita connection on a Lorentzian manifold the same as that on a Riemannian manifold?

Tags: connections, semi-riemannian-geometry

The Levi-Civita connection is defined by the Koszul formula to be independent of the metric. This applies to both Riemannian and pseudo-Riemannian metrics. In the latter, this is known as the miracle of semi-Riemannian geometry (p60 of Semi-Riemannian geometry with applications to relativity O'Neil). This seems to conclusively prove that the Levi-Civita connection is the same in both geometries. Certainly, the connection coefficients are also defined the same. Am I misunderstanding anything with that conclusion?

Comment: I suggest you write down the formula for the LC connection in terms of the metric. You will then see that it does depend on the metric. Actually, it is very seldom that two metrics have the same connection.

Comment: The connection, as defined by the Koszul formula, is independent of the metric. The torsion free connection is therefore the same is it not?

Comment: The axiomatic definition of a connection indeed does not need any metric. But this is not what I was talking about.

Comment: This means any non-degenerate metric determines a unique torsionless connection, the Levi-Civita connection.

Answer (score 1):

The "miracle" only means that given a semi-Riemannian metric $g$ on a manifold $M$ there exists a unique torsion-free affine connection $\nabla=\nabla_g$ which preserves $g$. The word **unique** here means that if $\nabla'$ is another torsion-free affine connection which preserves $g$, then $\nabla=\nabla'$. The uniqueness  here **does not** mean that if $h$ is another semi-Riemannian metric on $M$ then $\nabla_g=\nabla_h$. In fact, it is very seldom that two Riemannian metrics share the same connection. It is also seldom the case that if $g, h$ are semi-Riemannian metrics of different signature then  $\nabla_g=\nabla_h$.

Edit: If you want an explicit formula for the L-C connection (in terms of the Christoffel symbols), you have 
$$\Gamma^l_{jk} = \tfrac{1}{2} g^{lr} \left( \partial _k g_{rj} + \partial _j g_{rk} - \partial _r g_{jk} \right).$$
This is equivalent to the Koszul formula, but easier to parse. The semi-Riemannian metric enters this formula in the most obvious way.

Comment: Agreed and thanks for the clarification. There must be further conditions imposed on two connections to make them equivalent. For sure, if the geodesics of two connections are the same, and the connections are torsionless with the same parameterization (Spivak), then the connections are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, it is if and only if condition (for torsion-free connections).